# Server hardware setup/management certifications?

Tags: hardware, certificate

I know about CompTIA Server+ but are there any better/more impressive certifications?

Comment: Relevant experience is going to be much more impressive than any certifications when it comes to hardware.

Comment: I have to agree with Chris, I think experience is much better than any cert...

Comment: I don't think the question should be closed. There ARE hardware certifications available, and it's a valid sysadmin question, wanting to learn of those certifications.

Comment: I agree here with @dyasny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though experience is better than ANY cert whatsoever, there are certifications available for all the major brands. 
Dell: https://dtt.dell.com/Pages/Login/Welcome.aspx?LPID=e84SuJfu5ZI=  
HP:  http://www.hp.com/education/courses/hk753s.html   
IBM:  http://www-03.ibm.com/certify/